# Chimico analitico o analista chimico?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference, vocabulary

Un chimico che lavora nel campo della chimica analitica viene chiamato "chimico analitico" oppure "analista chimico"? Trovo entrambi sul web, vorrei capire se chimico analitico è scorretto.

Answer (score 7):

Ad occhio

- analista chimico = chi fa o si occupa di analisi chimiche (e.g. dell'acqua)
- chimico analitico = chi si è specializzato in chimica analitica

Potrei sbagliarmi, ma ad occhio mi sembra così.